# How to access the elements in the given matrix from top to bottom

Tags: python, python-3.6

Here's the matrix:

```
matrix = [   
    ['F', 'A', 'C', 'I'],   
    ['O', 'B', 'Q', 'P'],   
    ['A', 'N', 'O', 'B'], 
    ['M', 'A', 'S', 'S']
]
```

I want to access elements from top to bottom i.e.`FOAM`, `ABNA` and so on. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, but what you're looking for is some way to iterate over the list of lists.

```
 >>> [x[0] for x in matrix]
['F', 'O', 'A', 'M']
>>> [''.join(x[0] for x in matrix)]
['FOAM']
>>> [''.join(x[i] for x in matrix) for i in range(len(matrix))]
['FOAM', 'ABNA', 'CQOS', 'IPBS']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for elem in zip(*matrix):
    print(''.join(elem))
```

output

```
FOAM
ABNA
CQOS
IPBS
```

Answer (score 2):

You have different way to do this:

**Pure python**

You can using just pure python iterating the i-th elements of every row of your matrix. For convenience you can implement a function:

```
def get_col(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
```

Using the matrix you provided as example, to get the third column you can do something like this:

```
matrix = [['F', 'A', 'C', 'I'],   ['O', 'B', 'Q', 'P'],   ['A', 'N', 'O', 'B'], ['M', 'A', 'S', 'S']]
print(get_col(matrix, 3))
```

That print: `['I', 'P', 'B', 'S']`

**Using numpy**

However [numpy](https://numpy.org/) manage multidimensional very well, then you can convert your matrix in a numpy array and access it using the [indexing feature of numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html):

```
matrix = np.array([['F', 'A', 'C', 'I'],   ['O', 'B', 'Q', 'P'],   ['A', 'N', 'O', 'B'], ['M', 'A', 'S', 'S']])
print(matrix[:,3])
```

That print again: `['I', 'P', 'B', 'S']`